# when not to use the Asset object

Tags: administration, custom-object, configuration

I am considering using the Asset object however I am really put off by the fact that it presents as a page within a page which leads to a negative user experience. My business scenario requires that I have products installed at customer sites which are in effect assets, is there any alternative methodolgy to use  in order to avoid using Assets for this scenario?

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean when you say "presents as a page within a page". Assets display and behave just like any other standard related list item when it comes to creating/editing/viewing from the Account page. Are you referring to some other facet of their behaviour?

Comment: Correct and right! My apologies, I understand now that Assets is not available as a tab page therefore it is possible to create a hack that displays a webpage as a tab and this is applied to Assets, therefore Assets ends up as a page in a page. Is should really take down this question and try to find the way of displaying Assets as a tab without using that hack.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you can add assets as a tab under the profiles management section of setup - an administrator can make that change

There was a time that Assets didn't have a tab, but the [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BqwbAAC) for it was delivered in the [Spring '15 release](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring15/release-notes/rn_assets.htm).